# Database contains European dateformat but query searches on American date format

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Well, I'm using an MS Access database and I have a field Date. In the property of this field I have specified that the format should be 'dd/mm/yyyy'. However, when I use queries on the field, it searches with the date format 'mm/dd/yyyy'. I have no idea why it's doing this because I thought the queries adapt to the field properties and I haven't been able to find a solution online. My location and timezone are set in Europe. This is the query that I used:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS Amount
FROM Plays
WHERE PersonID = 1001 AND RestaurantID = 101358 and Date = #7/6/2016#
```

So, in this query it doesn't search the 7th of June 2016 but the 6th of July 2016. Both PersonID and RestaurantID are set as numbers; Date is set as Date/Time. How do I fix it so the query searches as the date format 'dd/mm/yyyy' as well without having to use any sql functions everytime?

Answer (score 0):

If your query is written in VBA, you MUST write the dates using m/d/y. That's it.
I tend to construct my SQL statements using `Format(expr, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")`. E.g:

```
const kUsDtFmt = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"
sSql =  "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE dtUpdated = " & Format(Date(), kUsDtFmt )
```

Note: "\" is the escape key in format strings, meaning that the next character is taken *as is*.

Comment: I tried this. It still doesn't return the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wish to filter on today's date, do this:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS Amount
FROM Plays
WHERE PersonID = 1001 AND RestaurantID = 101358 and [Date] = Date()
```

For other dates, use DateSerial which frees you from format considerations:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS Amount
FROM Plays
WHERE PersonID = 1001 AND RestaurantID = 101358 and [Date] = DateSerial(2016, 6, 7)
```

If you concatenate string expressions, use the ISO sequence:

```
Dim SomeDate As Date

SomeDate = DateSerial(2016, 6, 7)  ' or any other date value.
DateString = Format(SomeDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")

SQL = "SELECT Count(*) AS Amount " & _
    "FROM Plays " & _
    "WHERE PersonID = 1001 AND RestaurantID = 101358 and [Date] = #" & DateString & "#"
```

Note please, that *Date* is a reserved word, thus may have to be bracketed as shown.

Comment: I tried the last one but it returns a syntax error within which it shows #\#dd\/mm\/yyyy\##. This is one annoying problem hahahaha.

Comment: You didn't use my code. Read again and remove the extra "#".

Comment: I removed the extra "#" 's but it still gives a syntax error for some reason.

Comment: Doesn't the current setup only format the current date? I tried to incorporate my field Date in the format but that went... wrong. I tried this with in the query: Format(&"Date" &, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")

Comment: Yes. You used today's date. You can use any date value - see edited answer.

Comment: This didn't work out. However, I came up with an answer myself which I posted. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score -1):

Welp, I eventually found a solution to the problem:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as Amount FROM Plays WHERE PersonID = " & Me.txtPersonID &_
" AND RestaurantID = " & Me.txtRestaurantID & " AND Date = #" & Month(Me.txtDate)_
 & "/" & Day(Me.txtDate) & "/" & Year(Me.txtDate) & "#"
```

I expected some of your solutions to work but for some reason(s) they didn't. Anyhow, now the correct date is searched and the correct value is returned. Thanks for the time you spent helping me.

Comment: That's just a long-winded method to create a string expression for the date value which you normally would use `Format` for.

Comment: I know, I always use format as well but it just didn't work for some reason. I even had someone else look at it and there were no mistakes in the code.

Comment: Then reveal your secret code for us to find the mistake.

Comment: The expression I gave in my answer, equivalent to `format(txtDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")` works perfectly and is equivalent as your looong one

Answer (score -3):

Use `FormatDateTime` with `vbShortdate` to make sure your date is formatted the way the system expects it to be and not the way humans like to see it.

Comment: `FormatDateTime`is for display purposes, not for SQL which always requires string expressions for date/time values to be formatted with the ISO sequence or m/d US format.